# Using same menu item in multiple menus

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu, menu-item, navigation

I have 3 navigation menus on my website. The first menu contains 8 menu items. The second and third contain the same menu items but split with 4 on the left and 4 on the right.

Is there any way to duplicate menu items. I am aware they can share alias but I can't save them with the same names and I would like 'Home' 'About' 'Contact' to read the same on both the large 8 item and smaller 4 item menus.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a couple of options.  The notion of a 'duplicate' menu item could means several things - so to answer that bit I'll say - *sort of*.

1. In the second menu use a menu item alias to point to the first item.  The title can be the same as another item, the alias cannot be.  Your question seems to say the opposite is true, but you may mean something else.
2. Set the 2 shorter menu modules to use the main menu, and just hide the unwanted menu items with css (ie. display none).  This is what I would do if your menu stays pretty simple and stable.  It has the bonus of keeping you active menu item styles consistent and you only need one menu.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is use the URL menu option for the duplicate menu items. Obviously this could be an issue if you ever change URLs, but it avoids duplicate content due to multiple URLs for the same page, and is hidden from the page visitor.